# Where to find and download Dynamics CRM Instance adapter

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

where can I find official Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 or 2013 Instance Adapter ? for data synchronization between two CRM organization and migration to CRM Online ? Its missing on downloads.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft has removed CRM Instance Adapter feature and it's now being using the CRM 2013 SDK which has tool Configuration Migration Tool , that can transfer data from on-premise to another on-premise or CRM Online environment using xml/zip file with simple export/import.
More details:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/survivingcrm/archive/2014/06/09/configuration-migration-tool-working-smarter-with-metadata-entities.aspx